# How do I stop the Microsoft Sign In To Your Account dialog from popping up all the time

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, passwords, microsoft

On a Mac running macOS Monterey. I keep getting a popup asking me to "Sign In to your account" with MS Logo and listing out historical MS accounts I no longer use. I don't appear to have any web pages opening triggering the prompt and I have removed all cached credentials as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/sign-in/repeated-prompts-authentication) doc.
I have Office365 which is licensed to a different email address and im signed into O365 using this email and its different than the ones being suggested when the dialog pops up. Feels like this a Modern Workplace Authentication prompt but I cant see how to cleanse it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to fix the account popping up (log in with credentials). There is not another way I know. Then delete the account it you are not using it (Microsoft Live Login)

Comment: It sounds like a work laptop, right? Does this pop up only occur when you're not on the company's network (i.e. physically or through a VPN)?

Comment: I would make sure you logout of your account in Office and log back into it.  Sounds like Office is the culprit.

Comment: I logged out and back in to office with my hotmail credentials and then a few hours later I was prompted with a login prompt that contained a listing of the credentials from my last contract position. Maybe this is Modern Workplace Auth rather than office.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean modern authentication?

If so, please check if it is your issue: [You're repeatedly prompted for credentials when using modern authentication in Outlook 2016 for Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/send-receive-emails/prompted-for-credentials-modern-authentication).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end the problem was down to Exclaimer for Mac attempting to reauthenticate. Your answer was close enough to be helpful though --> https://support.exclaimer.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360042431672-How-to-uninstall-Exclaimer-Cloud-Signature-Update-Agent-for-macOS